# Как занести сертификат в  SSL context?

Tags: ssl, android, java

Сейчас есть такой код, как внести в SSLContext сертификат, который у меня ,пока, лежит на диске?

```
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
          return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] c, String a) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] c, String a) {}
    }};

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        SocketFactory socketFactory = ttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
        return socketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new UnknownHostException("Problems to connect" + host + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 способа:

1. Занести сертификат в сам аппарат - некоторые аппараты (например Samsung Galaxy) поддерживают импорт сертификатов из карты памяти
2. Создать собственную фабрику сертификатов реализовав интерфейс `X509TrustManager` - [пример здесь](http://nelenkov.blogspot.ru/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html#!/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html)

Comment: В методе getAcceptedIssuers() я должен буду вернуть список проверенных сертификатов?

Comment: public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new   FileInputStream(myCertFile));
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
...
        }